# how to NOT display empty objects from JSON file in DOM? Angular

Tags: json, angularjs, api, meetup

I'm using the Meetup API to display members photos

As you can see, some objects don't contain that property so it shows a blank div on my DOM. How can I just grab the json file with only the objects with that property?

or how can i display nothing if the object is empty?

Thanks in advance.

JS

```
nameAppControllers.controller('MemberCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.jsonp('https://api.meetup.com/2/members?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&offset=0&format=json&group_id=8247622&only=photo&photo-host=public&page=80&order=joined&sig_')
         .success(function(data) {
             $scope.members = data.results;
             console.log(data.results);
         });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="members" ng-controller="member in members">
    <div ng-repeat='member in members'>
      <div class='img-circle col-md-4'>
        <img ng-src="{{member.photo.highres_link}}">
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the html you are using to show the items? Or any code in general?

Comment: Thank you! Provided an answer using your html below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to do something like this -

```
<div class="members" >
   <div ng-repeat='member in members'>
      <div class='img-circle col-md-4' ng-show="!checkObject(member)">
         <img ng-src="{{member.photo.highres_link}}">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

And the function in the controller -

```
$scope.checkObject = function(obj) {
    return angular.equals({}, obj);
};
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/15233/)

Make a simple function to return true or false if the objet is empty or not and use that as a boolean for `ng-show`.

Comment: I added ng-show="member.length" but it doesn't display anything now. Is there anything I need to add to the JS file?

Comment: @KenRyan are you using that exact data you have linked up there?

Comment: Yes I am. its angular 1.3 also, not sure if that matters?

Comment: @KenRyan updated and gave you a fiddle so you can see it in action!

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

**controller**

```
$scope.isEmpty = function(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).length == 0;
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="members" ng-controller="member in members">
   <div ng-repeat='member in members'>
      <div ng-if="!isEmpty(member)" class='img-circle col-md-4'>
         <img ng-src="{{member.photo.highres_link}}">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Anik, I just updated my post with the code I am using. Where would I put the html you provided?

Comment: where would I put that piece of js ? inside the MemberCtrl?

Comment: It is similar to what @ajmajmajma provided but it didn't work for some reason. ng-show and ng-if have similar functionalites?